# Remove a language from the "Preferred language order"

Tags: ios, settings, language

How do I remove an added language form the "Preferred Language Order" in Settings > General > Language & Region > Preferred Language Order?

<sup>iPhone 6 Plus iOS 8.4.1</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Tap on edit on the top right of the screen:

[image: preferred language]

Then tap on the minus sign that will appear to the left of each language you want to remove

[image: edit language]

You can also rearrange the languages by dragging them; that will change the language in which apps and websites present themselves -as it says underneath:

> Apps and websites will use the first language in this list that they support.