# Spanish language invasion - can I limit a language to one app only?

Tags: ios, keyboard, language, text-input

My kids are in a Spanish immersion program and I have started using Duolingo to learn the language myself so that I can help them and practice with them. The app recommended that I enable the Spanish Keyboard as it's really useful for the device to fix my spelling and predict words *when I'm using Spanish*. Unfortunately, doing so has made it so that my text messages occasionally seem to prefer/suggest Spanish predictive text over English, which is frustrating since I don't use Spanish outside the Duolingo app (possibly related but not frustrating, I also see ads in Spanish now).

For example, if I start typing `don` it frequently seems to suggest "donde" instead of "don't", which means I have to type more before I can pick a predicted word (and if I get to `dont`, it may not ever recommend the correct "don't", which means I have to erase the `t`, switch to the character keyboard, manually add the apostrophe, and then continue typing.

#### Current settings:

iOS 16.6, iPhone 11 Pro

- General > Language & Region > English (iPhone Language), Español (Spanish)
- General > Keyboards > English (US), Emoji, Spanish (Mexico)

I have all of the "All Keyboards" corrections enabled, other than Smart Punctuation. There doesn't seem to be a way to set this on a per-keyboard basis but I'm not sure I want to in this situation.

I'm somewhat confused since I would expect since English is my first-listed and most-frequently used language, the phone *should* default to that (particularly when I'm using the English keyboard) but it doesn't seem to do so all the time.

#### Options / Questions

I've come up with two possible solutions and some questions but I'm not sure enough of how languages and keyboards work in iOS to know whether they're the "correct" one or if there are others I'm not aware of.

1. Remove Spanish language/keyboard from my phone entirely and only use Duolingo on my iPad as I don't text on it anyway. This is suboptimal as I like the flexibility of using the app on my phone if I don't have my iPad with me.
2. [Remove Spanish language](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201178/remove-a-language-from-the-preferred-language-order) (but keep the keyboard) - maybe having only the keyboard will prevent the attempts to predict Spanish words generally but will it still allow predictive text when I'm using the Spanish keyboard in the Duolingo app? I'm not even sure I can enable only the keyboard without the language.

   - This requires a restart, so I'm hesitant to do it if the keyboard and predictive text for that language requires the language.
3. Is there a way to disable predictive text for languages unless I'm using that specific keyboard? Maybe point two is exactly that?
4. Some apps (Notes, for example) let me set a prefered language manually in Settings. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to do that in Messages. Maybe it's in a different menu?

   - I can set it for Duolingo but the app already controls the keyboard I see depending on whether I'm being asked to respond in English or Spanish, so I don't think this will help.

So, the short form of the question is, **how can I control what languages I get text predictions for**, particularly in Messages or when using a specific keyboard? Or, alternatively, **can I set a language to be used only within a single app**?

Comment: When you say "without causing any problems" do you mean that when I use the Spanish keyboard, it will still predict Spanish words as I'm typing? My concern is that the phone restart is indicating that the phone has to add/remove dictionaries if the languages are changed, so if the Spanish dictionary is removed, would it be able to predict Spanish words any more?

Comment: The language list is irrelevant for the other things, it only governs the user interface language of the phone.  You can always put back the spanish dictionary separately if you want, but I would leave it off to see if that helps.